# How to stop sudo access for apt-get install command?

Tags: ubuntu, system-administration, ubuntu-server, server-administration

I am using ubuntu server on which some commands like

> apt-get install

needs sudo access so need to stop sudo access for that specific command i.e. while executing that command we don't need sudo access. So how to any solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

There are any number of ways to do this.

One which springs immediately to mind is to have a setuid script which does the job for you. Make it owned by `root` and also runnable by the group `aptgrp` (which you create and manage yourself).

The script will basically take arguments then call `apt-get` in turn, but as the `root` user.

However, I'd advise against this since you're creating a new tool with all the opportunities for getting security wrong. Especially since `sudo` can be configured in great detail in what programs you're allowed to run (no need to open up everything with `"pax ALL=(ALL) ALL"`) and whether or not you need to supply a password for it (the `"NOPASSWD"` clause).

I'd look into configuring `sudo` correctly before attempting any other solution.

Comment: On most systems, including Ubuntu, the setuid bit is ignored on scripts.